# Why aren't the lines sorted as expected in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have these lines:

```
'RECIPIENT_REFUSED',
'DELIVERED',
'DELIVERING_TO_DESTINATION',
'DRIVER_CONFIRMATION_PENDING',
'IN_PAYMENT',
'NOT_PAID',
'PAID',
'QUOTE_EXPIRED',
'QUOTE_REJECTED',
'QUOTE_UNDECIDED',
'TIME_CHANGED'
'ARRIVED_AT_DESTINATION',
'ARRIVED_AT_PICKUP',
'CANCELLED_BY_RECIPIENT',
'CANCELLED_BY_XXX',
'CANCELLED_BY_SHOP',
'CANCELLED_BY_TRANSPORT',
'DISPATCH_PENDING',
'DRIVING_TO_PICKUP',
'ITEMS_PICKED_UP',
'RECIPIENT_ABSENT',
```

Marking all of them and then running the *Edit* | *Line Operations* | *Sort Lines Lexicographically** (what ever option I select) doesn't sort the above lines properly. This is the result after a lexicographically ascending sort:

```
'ARRIVED_AT_DESTINATION',
'ARRIVED_AT_PICKUP',
'CANCELLED_BY_RECIPIENT',
'CANCELLED_BY_XXX',
'CANCELLED_BY_SHOP',
'CANCELLED_BY_TRANSPORT',
'DISPATCH_PENDING',
'DRIVING_TO_PICKUP',
---- Below this line the sort order is wrong but it doesn't change
---- when I re-run the sort functions
'ITEMS_PICKED_UP',             
'RECIPIENT_ABSENT',            
'RECIPIENT_REFUSED',           
'DELIVERED',                   
'DELIVERING_TO_DESTINATION',   
'DRIVER_CONFIRMATION_PENDING', 
'IN_PAYMENT',
'NOT_PAID',
'PAID',
'QUOTE_EXPIRED',
'QUOTE_REJECTED',
'QUOTE_UNDECIDED',
'TIME_CHANGED'
```

Am I doing something wrong, do I misunderstand the output of these functions, is my Notepad++ installation not configured properly or is it a Notepad++ bug? Any idea/hint?

Notepad++ 7.9.5 and these installed plugins:

- Mime tools 2.5
- Npp Converter 4.2.1
- NppExport 0.2.9

---

Update:

No hidden characters. This is an `ENUM` list from MySQL which I want to have sorted. All other tools sort it correctly.

---

Update:

Here the screenshot from NP++ showing all characters.

[image]

---

Update:

How to reproduce it:

This is the list copied from phpMyAdmin from the `ENUM` table field into an empty NP++ tab:

```
'ARRIVED_AT_DESTINATION', 'ARRIVED_AT_PICKUP', 'CANCELLED_BY_RECIPIENT', 'CANCELLED_BY_SFD', 'CANCELLED_BY_SHOP', 'CANCELLED_BY_TRANSPORT', 'DISPATCH_PENDING', 'DRIVING_TO_PICKUP', 'ITEMS_PICKED_UP', 'RECIPIENT_ABSENT', 'RECIPIENT_REFUSED', 'DELIVERED', 'DELIVERING_TO_DESTINATION', 'DRIVER_CONFIRMATION_PENDING', 'IN_PAYMENT', 'NOT_PAID', 'PAID', 'QUOTE_EXPIRED', 'QUOTE_REJECTED', 'QUOTE_UNDECIDED', 'TIME_CHANGED'
```

Then I replace all `,`  with `,\n` because *Line Split* doesn't split the lines.

The split lines are then sorted in this strange way.

Comment: 1) This belongs on [SU]. 2) [I can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/WaYsCS1.gif).

Comment: This also doesn't look reproducible to me.  Perhaps there are some hidden characters which we can't see.

Comment: @PeterVARGA A moderator or 3 users with the vote-to-close privilege can migrate it. However, at its current state, I don't think it should be migrated because the problem is not reproducible. If you open a new tab in Notepad++, copy the text _**from the question**_, and then try again, can you still reproduce the problem?

Comment: Use `View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters` or use a hex editor to identify the hidden chars if the first option didn't work.

Comment: Try replacing with `,\r\n` instead. Or if you can't work with `CRLF`, then switch `Edit > EOL Conversion` to `Unix (LF)` before sorting.

Comment: You're probably using Windows, so the default EOL mode for a new file is `CRLF` (AKA, `"\r\n"`). Now, when you split your values into lines, you're only using `"\n"` (LF). So, from the viewpoint of Notepad++ (with CRLF EOL mode), they are not technically separate lines (at least that's how it appears to be working).

Comment: @41686d6564 Thank you, I answered the question but it was solved by you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As user [41686d6564](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/41686d6564) pointed out it's the problem with my previously line split where I use for Windows document the Linux EOL.

*It can be fixed with one of these 2 options:*

1. Changing the EOL of the document to Linux when I use `,\n` for the replacement.
2. Using `,\r\n` if the document is in the Windows mode.

Comment: Thx for Q&A-ing this. This question bugged me quite a while already.